# Froda's Theorem for the geometric series consisting of $(1/2)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I need to verify that the following three properties will allow me to construct a monotone function on $\mathbb{R}$ whose set of discontinuities form a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

(Note: My textbook uses $\mathbb{E}$ to denote a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$.)

> Let $\mathbb{E}$ be any countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We construct a monotone function on $\mathbb{R}$ whose set of discontinuities is $\mathbb{E}$. First write $\mathbb{E}$ as a sequence of distinct points $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
>
> Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\,:\,x_n<x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> This summation means to sum over those indices $n$ for which $x_n<x$. If there are no indices $n$ such that $x_n<x$, then $f(x)=0$. Then:
>
> (a) $f$ is monotone increasing;
>
> (b) $f$ is discontinuous at every point of the countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, denoted as $\mathbb{E}$;
>
> (c) $f$ is continuous at every point of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{E}$.

I know that this function is a convergent geometric series, and that this series will converge absolutely. My intuition tells me that I will need to form a set of distinct points as $\mathbb{E}$ and then show that $f$ is not continuous at those points. Which seems obvious but I am having difficulty showing this explicitly.

So my question is, how would I construct this subsequence and show that they are discontinuous, and in the process verify the three points listed above?

Comment: b) and c) seem directly contradictory. How can $f$ be discontinuous at every point of $E$, and be continuous at every point of $E$? Also, what are the $x_n$ supposed to be? Do they have some relation to this mysterious $E$?

Comment: Ah I made a typo, let me fix that. Is that more clear now?

Comment: Better, but $x_n$ and $E$ are still mysterious.

Comment: I added another bit from my textbook that was above the question that I left out originally. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Yes, much better.

Comment: So, there's no subsequence to construct. $E$ is the set $\{\,x_1,x_2,\dots\,\}$. You have to show $f$ is monotone increasing, is discontinuous at $x_n$ for all $n$, and is continuous at all other $x$. Can you do the first of these, showing $f$ is monotone, that is, if $x<y$, then $f(x)\le f(y)$?

Comment: Yes, that I believe I can do. Out of these three, I am most unsure about parts (b) and (c). (We haven't really seen this in class yet, I am trying to work ahead).

Comment: For b), you should be able to show that for $x>x_k$, $f(x)-f(x_k)\ge2^{-k}>0$, and deduce discontinuity from that.

Comment: Great, thank you for the help. I will try that and see what I can do.

Comment: How's it going, Milton?

Comment: Well enough! I have an answer for a) and b), and am now stuck on c). When I come up with a complete answer for all three I will post it here. Thanks for checking in.